# Allow more characters in string:match()

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

```
string:match( "[^%w%s]" )
```

This currently allows only letters, numbers and spaces as far as I understand. How can I add characters to it? For example I'd like to allow `(` and `_` too.

Comment: Actually, it allows anything but letters, numbers, and spaces because of the leading ^ inside the [ ] set, which inverts the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string:match( "[^%w%s(_]" )
```

This would add the characters you mentioned. Basically any character you add in the square brackets.

Some need to be escaped, such as parentheses.

Comment: Lua pattern isn't regular expression.

Comment: They are similar, should work now, parens don't need escaping in square brackets, apparently.

Comment: Escaping them should also work, but the escape character is `%`, not bachslash.

Answer (score 1):

`^` in the beginning of a char-set means to get the complement. In your example, `[^%w%s]` matches a character that isn't a letter/digit(`%w`), or a whitespace `%s`.

If you need to add `(` and `_`, just add them: `[^%w%s(_]`